I want to send a file as an array in the body form-data through Postman. How can I do that?
I attached 2 files in the value, but I only received a single file.
this is code jQuery in Postman


var form = new FormData();
form.append("attachment", fileInput.files[0], "/C:/Users/nwp20/OneDrive/รูปภาพ/1333209348611219856.jpg");
form.append("attachment", fileInput.files[0], "/C:/Users/nwp20/OneDrive/รูปภาพ/1_JOq95cCfAGFBTHFGJPMcag.jpeg");

var settings = {
  "url": "http://localhost:800/see-talent-service/public/api/approval/87191?emp_detail_id=58496",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODAwXC9zZWUtdGFsZW50LXNlcnZpY2VcL3B1YmxpY1wvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTcxMTkzODU3OSwiZXhwIjoxNzExOTc0NTc5LCJuYmYiOjE3MTE5Mzg1NzksImp0aSI6ImF6MmNLM2dkYVlXYW03SHEiLCJzdWIiOjM2MTEyLCJwcnYiOiI4N2UwYWYxZWY5ZmQxNTgxMmZkZWM5NzE1M2ExNGUwYjA0NzU0NmFhIiwicm9sZSI6WzE1MzddLCJhZG1pbiI6dHJ1ZSwiY29tcGFuaWVzIjpbMTUsMTZdLCJzdWJfbGlzdCI6W10sImRlbGVnYXRlX2VtcF9kZXRhaWxfaWQiOltdfQ.8xOem9HJQp5YVd7-JO5ed0LinipK7hVOfTfFOy2ukX4"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});



